# What's better than a spray bottle for negative reinforcement of a cat?

Tags: cats, training

Spray bottles have some downsides:

1. Obviously, they get things wet
2. They make no sound so "warning" is impossible unless the cat notices you pick up the bottle
3. They get things wet.

**Is there a better alternative to the spray bottle?**

(I ask this question purely to educate, I found a much better and more effective solution)

Comment: Related: http://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/1448/spray-bottle-becoming-ineffective http://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/67/how-should-i-discipline-my-cat-for-bad-behavior/1072 - undecided if duplicates yet, still thinking

Comment: @Zaralynda That question asks if something can be added to the water. This one focuses on the issue of "warning" and the getting stuff wet issue. Different.

Comment: Yeah, I think they "feel" like duplicates to me because my answer is the same - I prefer to have behavior/consequences linked more directly and not rely on me noticing behavior and applying a correction (I'll always be inconsistent)

Comment: @Zaralynda I was thinking about that, but I think this kind of training is a basic, effective, quick solution for people who don't have the time or interest to apply more complex/superior training.

Comment: it could be a duplicate. We might have to close this but let's get more people involved with this question so that we can decide

Comment: The thing that has worked best for me is "Corporal Cuddling" where you hold the cat close to your chest and talk to it in SQUEAKY baby talk. All cats hate this!

Comment: @Oldcat Ginger loves it. She's just contrary.

Comment: I had a cat that used to drink from the spray bottle.

Answer (score 1):

## This thing.

[image]

The air spray duster is amazing.

1. **Warn.** Puff in the air, say "No.",
2. **Worked?** If not -> Puff cat, say "NO".

It took ***three times*** actually puffing the cat and now "No" is an instant "Stop what I'm doing" and when on the desk "Get in my bed" (I placed one on my desk behind the monitors where the cat would feel safe from the air spray) - **Very effective, and no water mess.**

---

**Note:** You shouldn't have to go further than a warn many times, but always hold the can right side up when spraying,  and **do not aim at the eyes or face.**

A very cold liquid can come out if the can is used incorrectly, and the back of the container warns that this "can cause frostbite".

Comment: For larger, more stubborn cats, [this usage of the duster](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DkQAkgfx2A4) may prove effective.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this works because the sound it makes is close to a cat hissing. It bothers my cats when I use them to clean my computer. Really, you I don't think you would need to point it at the cat at all. I actually think you might not even need to use it. If you can make a sharp "psst!" sound with your mouth it should be just as effective.

Comment: @MattS. nope, just tried it. Cat is still standing at my plate eating. Spray in the air didn't fix it this time either. A direct puff is extremely effective.

Comment: @MattS. can confirm that cats don't like air blown on them. We blow in their faces when they stand on our keyboards and they HATE the exhaust from my cpap.